# query apache drill form within apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-drill

I am querying Apache drill from within apache spark. My question is, how to send sql commands other than `select * from` from spark to drill. By default, spark is sending the queries inside select * from. Also, when I am querying schema other than dfs, I am getting NullPointerException. Please help!

My spark version is 2.2.0

Here are my codes:
1. schema = dfs:

```
dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:drill:zk=%s;schema=%s;" % (foreman,schema)).option("driver","org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","\"/user/titanic_data/test.csv\"").load()
```

2. Schema = MySQL

   `dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:drill:zk=%s;schema=MySQL;" % (foreman)).option("driver","org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","MySQL.\"spark3\"").load()`

This is the complete error:

```
Name: org.apache.toree.interpreter.broker.BrokerException
Message: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create prepared statement: SYSTEM ERROR: NullPointerException


[Error Id: d1e4b310-f4df-4e7c-90ae-983cc5c89f94 on inpunpclx1825e.kih.kmart.com:31010]
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newServerPreparedStatement(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:147)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newPreparedStatement(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:108)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newPreparedStatement(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:50)
    at oadd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(DrillConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at oadd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:119)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(DrillConnectionImpl.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o40.load.\n', JavaObject id=o41), <traceback object at 0x7f00106d6488>)
StackTrace: org.apache.toree.interpreter.broker.BrokerState$$anonfun$markFailure$1.apply(BrokerState.scala:163)
org.apache.toree.interpreter.broker.BrokerState$$anonfun$markFailure$1.apply(BrokerState.scala:163)
scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
org.apache.toree.interpreter.broker.BrokerState.markFailure(BrokerState.scala:162)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have changed the default drill quote from `` to "" so that there won't be any quoting identifier issue between spark and drill.

Comment: What's the exact error ?

Comment: The stack trace could help to solve your issue. From what place does the error occur?

Comment: The full stack is better. Won't do much about what causes the NPE here

Comment: please review the error. Thank you!

Comment: this is working fine for hdfs file. When I'm executing it for 'spark3' table in MySQL, it is failing with the above error.

Comment: Do you have successful query for dfs, right? You can try do not specify schema=%s in the url connecting string. You can then specify it explicitly in the query.

Comment: I tried that. It's showing `Table MySQL.spark3 Not Found`

Comment: I tried running the query that spark sent from drill web console. When I removed `WHERE 1=0`, the query is running fine. When I ran the query with `WHERE 1=0`, it's throwing `NullPointerException`